# How can adding a test case decrease code coverage in Jest?

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, jestjs, code-coverage

I just ran into a strange situation with a Jest test suite. I did not modify the code, but I added a test.

Before:

```
 mylibrary.js |   95.65 |    89.66 |     100 |   95.65 | 54-56,84       
---------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 3 passed, 3 total
Tests:       22 passed, 22 total
```

After:

```
 mylibrary.js |   95.65 |    89.29 |     100 |   95.65 | 54-56,84          
---------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 3 passed, 3 total
Tests:       23 passed, 23 total
```

I'm not able to share the code, but I want to ask: how is it possible that in Jest the test coverage would *decrease* when I am *adding* a test call?

The result I was expecting was an increase of 2 lines of coverage.

Using Jest 27.1.0. It's a pretty simple library with no dependencies.

(I have re-added/removed the test case to verify this isn't some weirdness caused by some other factor).

Comment: Only looking at the numbers and not seeing the project itself, in this case, is really hard to help. But there's an easy explanation. 22 tests. Remove 1 and you have 21 tests and less code coverage. Duplicate any test twice and you have 23 tests with code coverage of 21.

Comment: But that's describing a scenario which isn't this one. I'm not removing any tests, I'm simply adding one. Is there any reasonable explanation for this?

Comment: For anyone voting to close as "lacking debugging details", I'm really interested to know *in theory* what could cause Jest's code coverage to decrease when adding tests. I'm not particularly fussed about my current situation, and don't need debugging help - I was just very surprised that this could even happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `statements`, `functions`, and `lines` look identical, while your `branch` has decreased slightly. Looks like your new test has covered only one scenario of some branching logic, while not testing the alternate scenarios for the logic.

In general, it is possible to add tests and have the coverage decrease by either not covering all of the `statements`, `functions`, `lines` or `branch` paths. In this case it looks like your added test did not cover all the `branch` paths.

Check the `Uncovered Line #s` column for a line number that is colored yellow.

Comment: Ah! Is it because before, the coverage tool didn't even notice the existence of the branches, and now it notices them (because of a superficial test) and sees that they are not fully covered?

Comment: Hard to say without more details, but yes it is possible that your new test is executing code with uncovered branches that wasn't being executed before.